# Tumblr templating + static page specific HTML

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

A friend asked me to help them place a paypal button on their tumblr page. They had tried to place the code in the wysiwyg offered in the **page**'s editing panel, but that stripped the code needed for the button to work. *This is for good reason*, so I checkout out the theme template. In my experience, blog systems like this are gnarly long templates with a ton of `if page is 'about' { // show this }` type blocks with many post types and search and tag-tree mini templates etc. with everything you could ever need in the template rendered when appropriate.

I've looked over the documentation and I found a few useful keys: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#pages such as `{URL}`, `{Label}`, `{PostId}`, `{CurrentPage}`, `{ShortURL}` etc.

My first expectation would be that there may be a class on the body associated with the current page which I could use to hide/and show with just CSS (this is a just a quick fix for a friend) - but there is no class or id or anything I can hook into. I figured I could get some conditional templating such as:

```
{block:AboutPage}
  Only show on about page
{/block:AboutPage}
```

...but nothing like that exists as far as I can tell. I've tried using all of the page variables and haven't had any luck with any of my tests. Current page is referring to the index in a pagination setup... so it's always `1` on a static page. {ShortUrl} doesn't return anything. Is there a larger loop that I'm not understanding?

Conditional templating would be best, but I was at least hoping to build a tiny function that would add a slug to the body or something to get by. I used the label and dasherized it, which could work for CSS styles - but if he changes the page name it would break.

What am I missing? Is this not a standard need? Am I using the wrong search terms?

Here is an article with a hack to show something only on all static pages... http://beta.beantin.se/customised-tumblr-theme-static-pages/  but that doesn't really help me - and I think that `{StaticURL}` may have been changed since.

Comment: You can edit the theme HTML and put the button in there, it'll appear on every page of the blog. Do you want the button to appear only on the about page?

Comment: Yes. I want control over what HTML is shown on any specific static page.

Comment: When you edit a static page with wysiwyg editor, there's an option to switch to raw HTML, does that work?

Comment: No. The scripts and things that ensure the button works are stripped out on save.

Comment: Tumblr is really limited in editing of static pages. It allows in-line styling when clicking "html" in the page editor. You could add a script to the main page that adds stuff to the page depending on the URL. This is a method I have used in the past.

Comment: @chloe784 That is a good idea. I'm baffled as to why we would have to go to those lengths... but I guess I could put a target div in there for placement and append to it. The decision to limit 'pages' must be to keep tumblrs from being something other than a feed. Free websites wouldn't keep the community moving and connected may be their thoughts.

Comment: I just noticed that the default mobile tumblr theme is completely different than the desktop theme, in which case none of this shows up either. : ) So, I guess my quick attempt to help will really result in a complete re-write of this tumblr theme. : /

Comment: You can link to a remote js file in a static page

Comment: And you could add a class to each page using jquery/JavaScript

Comment: If either of these are of use, let me know and I can start to add an answer.

Comment: @lharby - Will do. I'm just letting this hang out for a bit longer. A combination of all these things is probably the answer. You also HAVE to turn off the default mobile theme to use any HTML on small screens.

Comment: Just remembered that iframes work in standard pages, so you could always make a custom page with the paypal button and no background or anything, (maybe centre it). Then insert the iframe for the custom page into the about page. This method works on mobile :)